# How to install the iOS profile programmatic?

Tags: ios, profile

I generate a profile though IPCU, and I put it on my http server. I wrote these code to install that profile.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/my.mobileprovision"];
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url;
```

When execute these piece of code, it will open the safari and then open the Setting to install the profile.

My question is **"how can I open the Setting app to install the profile programmatic, skipping the safari?"**

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip the Settings app to install a profile unless you use iPCU/XCode/Configurator/MDM. Apple dictates that all profiles be trusted by the end user so either the end user needs to tap Install within Settings or using Apple software (or MDM) via inherent trust since the device is in the hands of the person installing the profile. Not using this would allow for malicious, unwanted, or unsuspecting profiles & policies to be installed in a device.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the profile `embedded.mobileprovision` and embed the profile into the IPA. Once the IPA is installed on the phone, the profile is automatically added into system's profile list.